# Newly created home in a secondary hard drive keeps unmounting after restart, fstab does not work

Tags: linux, mount, fedora, reboot

I have bought a new hard drive and moved my home there. I have followed this link: https://www.howtogeek.com/442101/how-to-move-your-linux-home-directory-to-another-hard-drive/.

But the new hard drive keeps unmounting during restart and I always have to run `mount -a` command.

The new hard drive is `/dev/sda1`.

`blkid /dev/sda1` gives `/dev/sda1: UUID="7c34e1a9-bf29-4b8d-aaf7-e955b647575d" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ba042bba-01"`.

This is my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Thu Feb 18 09:11:13 2021
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk/'.
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info.
#
# After editing this file, run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to update systemd
# units generated from this file.
#
UUID=621d28d8-16de-44e8-b733-1dab40daea02 /                       btrfs   subvol=root,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 0 0
UUID=03011415-2410-443a-a923-ce1154ea8ea3 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=3D2C-76FF          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2
UUID=621d28d8-16de-44e8-b733-1dab40daea02 /home                   btrfs   subvol=home,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 0 0
#UUID=7c34e1a9-bf29-4b8d-aaf7-e955b647575d /home                   btrfs   subvol=home,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 0 0
/dev/sda1 /home ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
```

This is my `/proc/mounts` file:

```
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,size=4096k,nr_inodes=131072,mode=755,inode64 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,inode64 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,size=3187704k,nr_inodes=819200,mode=755,inode64 0 0
cgroup2 /sys/fs/cgroup cgroup2 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars efivarfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
bpf /sys/fs/bpf bpf rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700 0 0
/dev/mapper/luks-76241767-67a8-4d40-aafc-25eb50a2e22a / btrfs rw,seclabel,relatime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=257,subvol=/root 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=31,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=18047 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,seclabel,relatime,pagesize=2M 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tracefs /sys/kernel/tracing tracefs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
configfs /sys/kernel/config configfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,nr_inodes=1048576,inode64 0 0
/dev/mapper/luks-76241767-67a8-4d40-aafc-25eb50a2e22a /home btrfs rw,seclabel,relatime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=256,subvol=/home 0 0
/dev/loop2 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/2785 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop4 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/2721 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop3 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/15511 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop0 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/14946 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop7 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core22/607 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop1 /var/lib/snapd/snap/atomify/153 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop5 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1852 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core22/817 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop9 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop6 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1974 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop10 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop11 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/137 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop12 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-42-2204/120 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop15 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop13 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-42-2204/87 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop16 /var/lib/snapd/snap/rubymine/334 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop18 /var/lib/snapd/snap/signal-desktop/428 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop14 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1534 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop17 /var/lib/snapd/snap/rubymine/351 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop19 /var/lib/snapd/snap/signal-desktop/493 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop20 /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/17950 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop22 /var/lib/snapd/snap/xournalpp/69 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop21 /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/19457 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop23 /var/lib/snapd/snap/xournalpp/82 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/nvme0n1p2 /boot ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
/dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=winnt,errors=remount-ro 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/1000 tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1593852k,nr_inodes=398463,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64 0 0
portal /run/user/1000/doc fuse.portal rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
/dev/sda1 /home ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
```

This is my `/etc/mtab` file:

```
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,size=4096k,nr_inodes=131072,mode=755,inode64 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,inode64 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,size=3187704k,nr_inodes=819200,mode=755,inode64 0 0
cgroup2 /sys/fs/cgroup cgroup2 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars efivarfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
bpf /sys/fs/bpf bpf rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700 0 0
/dev/mapper/luks-76241767-67a8-4d40-aafc-25eb50a2e22a / btrfs rw,seclabel,relatime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=257,subvol=/root 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=31,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=18047 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,seclabel,relatime,pagesize=2M 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tracefs /sys/kernel/tracing tracefs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
configfs /sys/kernel/config configfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,nr_inodes=1048576,inode64 0 0
/dev/mapper/luks-76241767-67a8-4d40-aafc-25eb50a2e22a /home btrfs rw,seclabel,relatime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=256,subvol=/home 0 0
/dev/loop2 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/2785 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop4 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/2721 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop3 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/15511 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop0 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/14946 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop7 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core22/607 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop1 /var/lib/snapd/snap/atomify/153 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop5 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1852 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core22/817 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop9 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop6 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1974 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop10 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop11 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/137 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop12 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-42-2204/120 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop15 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop13 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-42-2204/87 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop16 /var/lib/snapd/snap/rubymine/334 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop18 /var/lib/snapd/snap/signal-desktop/428 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop14 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1534 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop17 /var/lib/snapd/snap/rubymine/351 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop19 /var/lib/snapd/snap/signal-desktop/493 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop20 /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/17950 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop22 /var/lib/snapd/snap/xournalpp/69 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop21 /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/19457 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/loop23 /var/lib/snapd/snap/xournalpp/82 squashfs ro,context=system_u:object_r:snappy_snap_t:s0,nodev,relatime,errors=continue 0 0
/dev/nvme0n1p2 /boot ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
/dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=winnt,errors=remount-ro 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/1000 tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1593852k,nr_inodes=398463,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64 0 0
portal /run/user/1000/doc fuse.portal rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
/dev/sda1 /home ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
```

Comment: (1) In your `fstab` there are two uncommented lines that try to mount at `/home`. Is this deliberate? (2) Do not use `/dev/sda1` in `fstab`. One day the disk will be `sdb1` and you will be surprised. Use `UUID=…`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski This is not deliberate but when I remove `UUID=621d28d8-16de-44e8-b733-1dab40daea02 /home                   btrfs   subvol=home,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 0 0` I cannot use computer, I have to edit `fstab` in emergency mode.

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/753116/108618).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a permission issue. I have reset the security label on the home partition mount point and its directories.

After `su`:

`restorecon -v /home /home/*`

Answer (score 0):

You hsve commented out the line in your ftab file to mount the drive (The line starting UUID=7c34e1a9-bf29-4b8d-aaf7-e955b647575d...) which refers to your new disk.

That entry also references the btrfs but the disk is ext4.  You may need to change the entry to reflect this.

Comment: I did it but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess as to what's going on here...

It looks like your original system is using btrfs. But if you followed that link's instructions, your new drive will be formatted as ext4. Mixing filesystems like that may work in theory, but may also entail additional configuration updates. Especially since it looks like an old line of the fstab has been configured with a btrfs subvolume for the home directory:

```
UUID=621d28d8-16de-44e8-b733-1dab40daea02   /home   btrfs   subvol=home,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 0 0
```

Further, I don't think you can have multiple block devices mounted to the same filesystem point. Only one entry in `/etc/fstab` can mount to `/home`.

E.g., your fstab should look something like this:

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Thu Feb 18 09:11:13 2021
# Updated by user on 2023-08-02
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk/'.
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info.
#
# After editing this file, run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to update systemd
# units generated from this file.
#
UUID=621d28d8-16de-44e8-b733-1dab40daea02   /       btrfs   subvol=root,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 0 0
UUID=03011415-2410-443a-a923-ce1154ea8ea3   /boot       ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=3D2C-76FF                  /boot/efi   vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2
UUID=7c34e1a9-bf29-4b8d-aaf7-e955b647575d   /home       ext4    rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
#
# older entries below
#
# original /home entry
#UUID=621d28d8-16de-44e8-b733-1dab40daea02  /home       btrfs   subvol=home,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 0 0
#
# likely wrong vfstype in column three (and thus wrong options in column four)
#UUID=7c34e1a9-bf29-4b8d-aaf7-e955b647575d  /home       btrfs   subvol=home,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 0 0
#
# Probably correct, but with obsolete /dev/sdX syntax. Use UUID.
#/dev/sda1                  /home       ext4    rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
```

Comment: Now I am not using the obsolete one, I use `UUID=7c34e1a9-bf29-4b8d-aaf7-e955b647575d /home ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime 0` but I still cannot remove `UUID=621d28d8-16de-44e8-b733-1dab40daea02  /home       btrfs   subvol=home,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 0 0`. This is weird.

Comment: Then it sounds like the btrfs filesystem is still expecting/needing to find the original `fstab` entry for `/home`. If the goal here was to move the home subvolume from one disk to another, then there might be btrfs-specific guides for such an endeavor.

Comment: So as I understand I have to set up my new hard drive with btrfs, right?

Comment: That would probably be the path of least resistance, yes.

Comment: I will try it and inform you.

Comment: Roger that. Be careful that you back up your data before formatting any disks.

Comment: Data is everything. :)

Comment: It still works with the old entry. This might be important: my first hard drive is encrypted and I think my second hard drive is not.